# How to list all tables with sqlite in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am using SQLite.swift and I want to list all tables in my database.

I tried the following SQL statements.

```
database.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
```

I only get empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database.execute does not return a value, it only executes the statement on the database. You can see it does not return in the source code:

```
// MARK: - Execute



/// Executes a batch of SQL statements.

///

/// - Parameter SQL: A batch of zero or more semicolon-separated SQL

///   statements.

///

/// - Throws: `Result.Error` if query execution fails.

public func execute(_ SQL: String) throws {

    _ = try sync { try self.check(sqlite3_exec(self.handle, SQL, nil, nil, nil)) }

}
```

Instead of execute, you can using the selection query DSL defined in the documentation [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#selecting-rows)